# I am trying to convert this button action to MVC architecture. I am new to python

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
class View:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.container = parent
        self.setup()
        

    def setup(self):
       self.create_audio_frame()

    def create_audio_frame(self):
       self.upload_button = Button(self.leftFrame, text='Upload Audio File', command=lambda: self.UploadAction() )    


    def setup_audio_frame(self):
        self.upload_button.pack(pady=10)

    def UploadAction(self):
        global path
        audios = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
        for audio in audios:
            path = os.path.split(audio)
            audio = path[1]
            self.audio_box.insert(END, audio)

            path = f'{path[0]}/'
```

I dont know where to move this upload action. i mean to controller or model. i tried to move to controller, the file dialog box is opening without clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a controller class. It needs to know about the other classes. A convenient way to do that is to have it create the other classes. You can then pass the controller to each class so that they can call functions on the controller.

Here's one way to do it:

```
class Controller(...):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.view = View(controller=self)
        self.model = Model(controller=self)
        ...

    def uploadAction(self, audios):
        for audio in audios:
            path = os.path.split(audio)
            audio = path[1]
            self.view.add_audio(audio)
```

With that, we can create a view that can call `uploadAction` on the controller, and then the controller can call the view to update the display:

```
class View(...):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ... 

    def create_audio_frame(self):
        ...
        self.upload_button = Button(..., command=self.uploadAction) 
        ...   

    def uploadAction(self):
        audios = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
        self.controller.uploadAction(audios)

    def add_audio(self, audio):
        self.audio_box.insert(END, audio)
```

Comment: Thank you. What should be in the model. Eg. what kind of logic

Comment: @Santhiyas: I don't know what should be in the model, you haven't given enough information. The model contains whatever data your program manages.